# The property of the functor "Hom"

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

If $ i\in I$ and $\ I $ is an infinite index set, $\ A,A_i ,B,C$ are all R-module,  is it true for$\ Hom_R(\bigoplus A_i,B) \cong Hom_R(\prod A_i,B)$?

And when is it true for $\ Hom_R( A,B\bigoplus C) \cong Hom_R(A,B)\bigoplus Hom_R(A,C)$?

All the above is true, but it seems $\ Hom_R(B,\bigoplus A_i) \ne \bigoplus Hom_R(B,A_i)$ but $\ Hom_R(B,\prod A_i)\cong \prod Hom_R(B,A_i)$?

Comment: Yes and yes. Hom always sends coproducts in the first variable and products in the second variable to products.

Answer (score 2):

Both isomorphisms are true. For the first one, note that for any $i$ there is a natural map (by restriction)

$$Hom_R (\bigoplus A_i, B) \to Hom_R (A_i, B)$$

so this lifts to a map $ Hom_R (\bigoplus A_i, B) \to \prod Hom_R (A_i, B)$. To check this is indeed an isomorphism, notice that it has to be injective, since the morphism at the $A_i$ allows us to determine the morphism at the direct sum. It must also be surjective because you can define the morphism to be however you want on the $A_i$ and this gives a valid morphism on the direct sum. The map will send this to the product of each of the $A_i$ morphisms.

For the other isomorphism, you could actually have an arbitrary direct sum, and this factors as a direct sum as well. The idea is very similar since by inclusion we have a natural map

$$Hom_R (A, B_i) \to Hom_R (A, \bigoplus B_i)$$

This then lifts to a map on the direct sum and you can apply a similar reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the following: If $I$ is an arbitrary indexed set it holds that $$\text{Hom}(\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i,N) \cong \prod_{i \in I}\text{Hom}(M_i,N).$$ However it "commutes" with direct sums, whenever you have a finite direct sum, meaning: $$\text{Hom}_R(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i,N) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \text{Hom}(M_i,N)$$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that this also holds for products/sums in the second variable. One can prove the first statement by looking at the map $$\text{Hom}(\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i,N) \to \prod_{i \in I}\text{Hom}(M_i,N), \varphi \mapsto (\varphi \circ \iota_i)_{i \in I}.$$